# How do you find the resulting frequency of sampling a tone at too slow of a rate?

Tags: frequency, signal-processing, sound, sampling, aliasing

For example, I have a 1500 Hz tone that I am going to be sampling at 1200 samples/second. How would I figure out the tone resulting from this sampling?

Comment: 1200 is more than 2x500, so I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Whoops. I meant to write 1500 Hz. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: This just uses the standard modulation formula.

Comment: 1500Hz aliases to 900Hz (sample rate 1200Hz +- 300Hz). The system will not be able to distinguish between 1500Hz and 900Hz tones. Nor can it distinguish 900Hz from any other aliases: 2400Hz +- 300Hz, 3600Hz +- 300Hz, 4800Hz +- 300Hz, etc.

Comment: @MarkU That's an answer, and the only correct one so far.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Actually, I disagree. You can't end up with a 900 Hz signal when you are sampling at 1200 Hz. With 1200 Hz sample rate, you know you only have a bandwidth of 600 Hz.

Comment: @BlairFonville is correct, I should have used 600Hz (fs/2) instead of 1200Hz (fs) as the alias limit.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaah wait a second. I just got bamboozled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subsample frequency can be found as

**f<sub>sub</sub>** = f<sub>c</sub> *mod* f<sub>samp</sub>

so, **300 Hz**, in your case.

For a more complete solution, here's what I do in Matlab:

```
function Fif = SubsampleMap(f, fs)

   f_new = mod(f,fs);
   if f_new > fs/2
       Fif = fs-f_new;
   else
       Fif = f_new;
   end
```

In other words, if the *mod* operation translates to the imaginary frequency, adjust it to the real one.

Comment: I thought that a sampling rate of twice the frequency was needed to reconstruct the signal. Using your formula, wouldn't any frequency that is below the sampling rate (not below half the sampling rate) be able to be reconstructed? What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: @user1953907 Yes. Good catch. I was only posting the equation directly related to your frequencies. I've updated the post to include any freq. pair.